# How to create a timer that counts up with server side controls, but client side display?

Tags: timer

I want to write a timer that counts up, no preference of code, that has controls to start and stop the timer on my server, but displays the time on the clients computer.  I can offer more information if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to provide more information. It's not clear if you're talking about persisting the timer on a per user basis with a database or just using a simple javascript implementation.

Comment: Ok, so I am starting a business that charges per hour, and I want to be able to start the timer when I start working, and have the display be output on the clients computer when they login with their account on my website.  I can write an algorithm that will calculate the price based on the time, but I don't know how to write the timer.  Does that help or do you need more info??

Comment: I want them to be able to view the timer so they can know the amount of money they owe me in real time.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is a database. I'd go with MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/), since it's good and free. If you're paying for hosting you might already have access to a database though.

Then you need some tables to store the necessary info. How you create them depends on your database, but I'll make a rough outline.

You'd typically have a customer table with info about your customer:

| Customer Id | Customer name | Contact person | Phone | E-mail |

Then a table for each of the project your doing for your customer (here you'll have a foreign key to the customer table):

| Project Id | Customer Id | Cost per hour | Estimated hours | Start date | Finish date |

And here's the table that will be updated whenever you start or stop working on the project. There will be a new row in this table every time you "stop the timer" on the project (project Id is a foreign key to the previous table. Customer id is optional, since you can get at the customer through the second table):

| Session Id | Project Id | Customer Id | Start | Stop |

Here "start" and "stop" are timestamps. Session id is an auto incremented id. Each time you start the timer, that corresponds to inserting a new row into the table with the current time in the start field. Each time you stop the timer, that corresponds to setting the current time in the stop field for the only row with the current project where the stop date is null.

When the customer wants to know the total time spent on the project so far, that's a matter of summing all the intervals (stop - start) on the projects.

To make use of any of this, you need to make a framework in some kind of programming language. I prefer perl myself, but php is probably your best bet, since it's well suited for these kinds of things.

It's hard to go into more specifics until you've made some design choices, but I hope this is enough to give you a general idea of how you can implement it.

Comment: I've got a sql server already set up, I just needed to know what rows to put in the table.  I'll try this right now.  Thanks a lot!!